# Embedding CRL response in signed PDF breaks PDF/A-2B conformance

Tags: pdf, itext

With iText 5.5.4, if I choose to embed CRLs during the signature process, it breaks the PDF/A-2B conformance because of a *String too long* error :

[Adobe Preflight http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/234201so5.jpg](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/234201so5.jpg)

As you can see in the preflight from Adobe Acrobat Pro 11.0.09, the CRL is 67107 characters long whereas this specific PDF standard require that the maximum length for strings must not exceed 32767 bytes.

Is it a bug in Itext or is there a way to keep PDF/A-2B conformance in that case?

Comment: *the CRL is 67107 characters long* - well, most likely the space reserved for the signature container has that size, but the CRL embedded therein indeed seems to require much of that space. Can you share the PDF in question to check whether the CRL indeed is that large or whether too much space has been reserved for the signature. One option might be a PAdES-4 style document security store to use for the CRL instead of the signature container. Compatibility of PDF/A-2 and DSS would have to be checked, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Is it a bug in Itext?

> As you can see in the preflight from Adobe Acrobat Pro 11.0.09, the CRL is 67107 characters long whereas this specific PDF standard require that the maximum length for strings must not exceed 32767 bytes

Considering that the problem string is referenced as `1 0 obj/Contents` seems to indicate that it actually is the string reserved for the CMS signature container, not the plain CRL.

Looking at the PDF/A specification (I only have part 3 at hands but the parts 2 and 3 should coincide here) there are two sections which seem to contradict each other:

> A conforming file shall not contain any string longer than 32767 bytes.
>
> *(section 6.1.13 Implementation limits)*

and

> timestamping and revocation information should be included [in the PDF Signature (a DER-encoded PKCS#7 binary data object)] in order to improve the long-term non-repudiation properties of the signature.
>
> *(Annex B Requirements for digital signatures in PDF/A)*

In your case following the latter recommendation breaks the former requirement because the PKCS#7 / CMS object is embedded as a string in the PDF.

But as we have a requirement against a recommendation, the recommendation need only be followed as long as the requirements are not violated. The specification even explicitly says so:

> When generating signature appearances and any other PDF objects as part of the signing process, a
>   conforming reader shall ensure that it does not invalidate compliance with this part of ISO 19005
>
> *(section 6.4.3 Digital signatures)*

Thus indeed, **iText signing should fail during the signing process... if you have used the PDF/A aware API**, that is. Unfortunately you have not provided your source code, so it is not clear whether or not you have used the `PdfAStamper` or merely the `PdfStamper`.

### Or is there a way to keep PDF/A-2B conformance in that case?

You didn't supply your source code, so this can only be answered in a more general way.

First of all check whether the space reserved for the signature container is really required or whether there are many padding bytes. In the latter case fine tune the reservation code.

If that does not suffice, embedding the CRL into the signature container automatically results in a violation of PDF/A conformance and, therefore, is not allowed.

One option would then be to try to use OCSP responses instead of CRLs here. OCSP responses usually contain information for only one or at most very few certificates while CRLs can become quite big.

If the CA does not have OCSP servers, I don't see a true PDF/A-2'ish solution. You might want to try to embed validation related information in PAdES part 4 (ETSI TS 102 778-4) DSS (Document Security Store) structures instead of in the signature container. Plain PDF/A viewers most likely won't recognize, let alone use, the CRL there but more versatile viewers, e.g. current Adobe Reader versions, should.